# Forwarding an email as an attachment with a bash shell script, or applescript

Tags: shell-script, osx, email

I would like to forward email as an attachment, in order to satisfy my ISP's (Comcast) rules for sending them spam email to be blocked. There is a "Forward as Attachment" feature in the MAC Mail menu but I want to be able to set the recipient (and a Cc), the subject and add some text to the body of the email, all in one step. I am using a MAC Book PRO, with El Capitan v.10.11.6.